# Limit if open files mistake on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, centos5

On my centos 5.5 server,i set in limits.conf with bellow:

```
* soft nofile 409600
* hard nofile 409600
```

but when i issue command:ulimit -n. It tell me :

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

I had `set fs.file-max=1188373` in /etc/sysctl.conf.
I don't know where is wrong.Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: So about cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there maybe some rule inside /etc/security/limits.d/ overriding your settings?

Comment: Do you try `sysctl -p`. Give the result of command `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn`

Comment: It is empty in /etc/security/limits.d.@Pascal Schmiel

Comment: have you re-logged in after you've set the new limits?

Comment: @Gnouc .sysctl -a|grep file :fs.file-max = 1188373 .ulimit -HSn :1024

Comment: The limits were set long long ago.I checked the mistake today. @Pascal Schmiel

Answer (score 0):

In case it is not just a mistake in the question, I'd suggest to put just `fs.file-max=1188373` in /etc/sysctl.conf instead of prefixing this with `set`.

Then load it with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` and check, as was already suggested, with `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` if it had any effect.

Comment: sysctl -a|grep file :fs.file-max = 1188373 . cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
  1188373    @Stefan Eggers

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
1188373

Comment: OK, so that is working. Does /etc/pam.d/system-auth (probably a symlink to system-auth-ac) contain a line with pam_limits.so in it?